# What is the Key property of IdentityServer in AppSettings.Json

Tags: c#, .net, single-page-application, duende-identity-server, duende

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#deploy-to-production) from microsoft to secure a dotnet SPA with Duende Identity Server. According to the tutorial, I should configure the "Key" section of "IdentityServer" in AppSettings.json in order to sign the tokens. For development you use the following:

```
"IdentityServer": {
  "Key": {
    "Type": "Development"
  }
}
```

However, according to Duende's documentation [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/fundamentals/keys/), Identity server uses automatic key management by default, and I am using

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

to persist keys to a database.

If Identity Server automatically manages and rotates the keys it uses, then what is the purpose of the "Key" section, and how should it be configured for production? I have not been able to find much information about it. If I remove it I get this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: No signing credential is configured by the 'IdentityServer:Key' configuration section.
```

Comment: Great question!